# Accessing and Updating Cached Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, concurrency

I have a Dictionary (concurrent) which is used to map one object id to another. Getting the value id based on the input key is rather expensive, so I want to persist the dictionary in the server cache.

I have a first-blush attempt at a method to do this, however it just "feels" like there could be a better way to do it:

```
private string GetItem(string cacheKey, string itemKey)
{
    string sfAccountId = null;
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> sfAccountMap =
            Context.Cache[cacheKey] as ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>;
    if(sfAccountMap == null)
    {
        lock(cacheLock)
        {
            sfAccountMap = Context.Cache[cacheKey] as ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>;
            if(sfAccountMap == null)
            {
                sfAccountMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
                sfAccountId = ExpensiveMethodReturnsString();
                if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sfAccountId))
                {
                    sfAccountMap.TryAdd(itemKey, sfAccountId);
                }
                Context.Cache[cacheKey] = sfAccountMap;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(sfAccountMap.ContainsKey(itemKey))
        {
            sfAccountMap.TryGetValue(itemKey, out sfAccountId);
        }
        else
        {
            sfAccountMap.TryAdd(itemKey, ExpensiveMethodReturnsString());
            lock(cacheLock)
            {
                Context.Cache[cacheKey] = sfAccountMap;
            }
        }
    }
    return sfAccountId;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your code can be simplified, while still doing what it is doing now.

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> GetCachedAccountMap(string cacheKey)
{
    var map = Context.Cache[cacheKey] as ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>;
    if (map == null) 
    {
        lock (cacheLock) 
        {
            map = Context.Cache[cacheKey] as ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>;
            if (map == null)
                map = Context.Cache[cacheKey] = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
        }
    }
    return map;
}

private string GetItem(string cacheKey, string itemKey)
{
    return GetCachedAccountMap(cacheKey)
        .GetOrAdd(itemKey, k => ExpensiveMethodReturnsString());
}
```

Note: given that it is unlikely to have concurrent access to the cache while the account map is not yet there, and it appears that it is not so bad in that very exceptional case if you do one extra allocation and call to the expensive method, the `GetCachedAccountMap` method could be further simplified, by not using any locks.

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> GetCachedAccountMap(string cacheKey)
{
    var map = Context.Cache[cacheKey] as ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>;
    if (map == null) 
        map = Context.Cache[cacheKey] = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, that looks better.